# JQuery Validation Plugin : Unable to validate the second setp of bootstrap wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, wizard

I have an jquery step wizard (3 steps), inside of them exists one form. When pass to the next step i try validate the first step form fields with valid() method (it's ok'), but when I try to validate second step jquery validate always return true. So it pass to the third and end step without validate second step. How to do it, please ?

I Have 1 function for validation for every wizard step.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*  Activate the tooltips      */
    $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      
    $('.wizard-card').bootstrapWizard({
        'tabClass': 'nav nav-pills',
        'nextSelector': '.btn-next',
        'previousSelector': '.btn-previous',
         
         onInit : function(tab, navigation, index){
            
           //check number of tabs and fill the entire row
           var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
           $width = 100/$total;
           
           $display_width = $(document).width();
           
           if($display_width < 600 && $total > 3){
               $width = 50;
           }
           
           navigation.find('li').css('width',$width + '%');
           
        },
        onNext: function(tab, navigation, index){
            if(index == 1){
                return validateFirstStep();
            } else if(index == 2){
                return validateSecondStep();
            } else if(index == 3){
                return validateThirdStep();
            } //etc. 
              
        },
        onTabClick : function(tab, navigation, index){
            // Disable the posibility to click on tabs
            return false;
        }, 
        onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
            var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
            var $current = index+1;
            
            var wizard = navigation.closest('.wizard-card');
            
            // If it's the last tab then hide the last button and show the finish instead
            if($current >= $total) {
                $(wizard).find('.btn-next').hide();
                $(wizard).find('.btn-finish').show();
            } else {
                $(wizard).find('.btn-next').show();
                $(wizard).find('.btn-finish').hide();
            }
        }
    });

    // Prepare the preview for profile picture
    $("#wizard-picture").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    
    $('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').click(function(){
        wizard = $(this).closest('.wizard-card');
        wizard.find('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(wizard).find('[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).find('[type="radio"]').attr('checked','true');
    });
    
    $('[data-toggle="wizard-checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).find('[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked','true');
        }
    });
    
    $height = $(document).height();
    $('.set-full-height').css('height',$height);
    
    
});

function validateFirstStep(){
    
    $(".wizard-card form").validate({
  rules: {
   firstname: "required",
   lastname: "required",
   email: {
    required: true,
    email: true
   }

  },
  messages: {
   firstname: "Please enter your First Name",
   lastname: "Please enter your Last Name",
   email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            
  }
 }); 
 
 if(!$(".wizard-card form").valid()){
     //form is invalid
     return false;
 }
 
 return true;
}

function validateSecondStep(){
   
    //code here for second step
    $(".wizard-card form").validate({
  rules: {
            matri: "required"
  },
  messages: {
            matri: "Matricule required"
  }
 }); 
 
 if(!$(".wizard-card form").valid()){
     console.log('invalid');
     return false;
 }
 return true;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just replace you refreshAnimation function**

**From :**

```
function refreshAnimation($wizard, index){
    total_steps = $wizard.find('li').length;
    move_distance = $wizard.width() / total_steps;
    step_width = move_distance;
    move_distance *= index;

    $wizard.find('.moving-tab').css('width', step_width);
    $('.moving-tab').css({
        'transform':'translate3d(' + move_distance + 'px, 0, 0)',
        'transition': 'all 0.3s ease-out'

    });
}
```

**To**

```
function refreshAnimation($wizard, index){
    total_steps = $wizard.find('.nav li').length;
    move_distance = $wizard.width() / total_steps;
    step_width = move_distance;
    move_distance *= index;

$wizard.find('.moving-tab').css('width', step_width);
$('.moving-tab').css({
    'transform':'translate3d(' + move_distance + 'px, 0, 0)',
    'transition': 'all 0.3s ease-out'

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all validations rules in the first step

```
$(".wizard-card form").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        matri: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your First Name",
        lastname: "Please enter your Last Name",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        matri: "Matricule required"
    }
});
```

and check validation in second step

```
function validateSecondStep(){

//code here for second step

if(!$(".wizard-card form").valid()){
    console.log('invalid');
    return false;
}
return true;
```

}